# Favourite Unfavourite From Axios API in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am fetching data from An Api, Array is coming fine, In the V-For Loop

```
<div style="width: 20px; float: right">
<i class="fa fa-heart-o"  @click="favourite(item.content_id)" v-if="item.is_fav_status == 0"></i>
<i class="fa fa-heart"  @click="favourite(item.content_id)" v-if="item.is_fav_status == 1"></i>
</div>
```

So If, it is coming '0' from response then it is not favourited, and if it is '1' then its favourited already.

Now, If its not favourited, and Upon Click, It is getting Favourite Successfully using some POST Api, But I want to make it reactive, So Icon and Function Change Accordingly, Upon Doing Favourite and Unfavourite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the whole item to the click handler:

```html
@click="favourite(item)"
```

In there, toggle the value, along with whatever you are already doing with the `content_id`:

```js
async favourite(item) {
  const response = await axios.post(url)   // Existing call can use `item.content_id`

  item.is_fav_status = !item.is_fav_status;  // Toggle the value
}
```